# Let X and Y be i.i.d. N(0, 1), and let S be a random sign (1 or -1, with equal probabilities) independent of (X, Y).

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Let X and Y be i.i.d. N(0, 1), and let S be a
random sign (1 or -1, with equal probabilities) independent of (X, Y).

(a) Determine whether or not (X, Y,X + Y) is Multivariate Normal.

(b) Determine whether or not (X, Y, SX + SY) is Multivariate Normal.

(c) Determine whether or not (SX, SY) is Multivariate Normal.

I have gotten to the matrix part but not sure how to show if they are multivariate or not. Here is where I am up to.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/xZWzE]

Comment: The computations of expectations and variances are offtopic. Re (a), use that every linear transform of a normal vector is a normal vector. Re (b), note that $P(X+Y+(SX+SY)=0)=P(S=-1)=\frac12$ and that no normal random variable $Z$ is such that $P(Z=0)=\frac12$. Re (c), note that $(X,Y)$ and $(-X,-Y)$ are identically distributed hence $P((SX,SY)\in B)=P((X,Y)\in B,S=1)+P((-X,-Y)\in B,S=-1)=\ldots$