# Determining multivariate normality

Tags: probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. $N(0, 1)$, and let $S$ be a random sign (1 or -1, with equal probabilities) independent of $(X, Y)$.

Determine whether or not $(SX, SY)$ is Multivariate Normal.

My attempt is:

$k_1SX + k_2SY = S(k_1X + k_2Y)$ for some constants $k_1$ and $k_2$

As $W = (k_1X + k_2Y)$ is normally distributed, we can show that $Z = SW$ is normally distributed as,

\begin{align*}
P(Z \leq z) & = P(Z\leq z|S=1)P(S=1) + P(Z\leq z|S=-1)P(S=-1)\\
& =  0.5P(W \leq z)+0.5P(W\leq z)\\
& = P(W \leq z).
\end{align*}

Hence the distribution of $Z$ is normal for any choice of $k_1$ and $k_2$.

Is there anything wrong in this proof.

---

Attempt 2: As for the calculations given in [Let X and Y be i.i.d. N(0, 1), and let S be a random sign (1 or -1, with equal probabilities) independent of (X, Y).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987113/let-x-and-y-be-i-i-d-n0-1-and-let-s-be-a-random-sign-1-or-1-with-equal-p)

\begin{align*}
P((SX,SY)∈B)&=P((X,Y)∈B,S=1)+P((−X,−Y)∈B,S=−1) \\
&= P((X,Y)∈B)P(S=1)+P((−X,−Y)∈B)P(S=−1)\\
&= 0.5*P((X,Y)∈B) + 0.5*P((−X,−Y)∈B)\\
&= P((X,Y)∈B)
\end{align*}

Which one is the correct answer?

Comment: Same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987113/let-x-and-y-be-i-i-d-n0-1-and-let-s-be-a-random-sign-1-or-1-with-equal-p?rq=1. See the comment.

Comment: True. However, I am not sure how to solve it in that way. So I tried another way of getting it.

Comment: You are using a theorem that two random variables have a joint normal distribution if all linear combinations are normal. The question is too elementary and using this theorem doesn't  seem justified.

Comment: If it is wrong, how can I prove or disprove multivariate normality in here?